# How to use PySpark to run SQL aggregations on Cassandra row values?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, cassandra, pyspark

I am currently using issuing 1000s of queries in python to cassandra. The row values looks something like this

```
{'company_id': 1234, 
 'locations': ['sf', 'sj'...], 
 'attributes':[{'action': 'page_visit', 'timestamp': 123, 'address': reddit.com/asdf}, 
               {'action': 'email', 'timestamp': 125', 'subject': 'stuff},
               {'action': 'update', 'timestamp': 127, 'email': 'new_email@gmail.com'}]
  ...}
```

I process the data by picking out specific fields and subfields such as company_id, page visits from the attributes field and then running aggregations.  The rest of the table has deeper nestings.

I want to use PySpark to parallelize the queries and issue SQL (not CQL) queries on the row values.  The rows are nested json so I would need to write a custom mapping from the json to a columnar object. Is this possible without writing to a temporary table?

Comment: how data looks like inside Cassandra? as lists/maps?

Comment: Each row's value is a map. The values may be nested maps, lists, ints, strings etc.  I'm fairly certain something would need to be written to flatten the map to key: value pairs but I'm not sure how this would be done.